# Index-Match (find last value which matches criteria)

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup, importrange

I am trying to have my Index match formula in Google Sheets return the last matching value in a series of values. Currently of course it only returns the first:

```
=INDEX (IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FAkqI_IDrWREzppeLkxx43TnSyrWs9ayS_R__l7RU/edit#gid=1044750","'Form Responses 1'!C1:C"),MATCH(B5, IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FAkqI_IDrWREzppezkxx43TnSyrWs9ayS_R__l7RU/edit#gid=1044750","'Form Responses 1'!AA1:AA"),0))
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Really Appreciated
Dan

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=VLOOKUP(B5, SORT({
 IMPORTRANGE("1FAkqI_IDrWREzppezkxx43TnSyrWs9ayS_R__l7RU", "'Form Responses 1'!AA1:AA"), 
 IMPORTRANGE("1FAkqI_IDrWREzppezkxx43TnSyrWs9ayS_R__l7RU", "'Form Responses 1'!C1:C")}, 
 1, 1), 2, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. This worked great except some entries were not sorting in order. I added 2 more criteria to yhe end of your line; 1,1,2,false),2,0) and it now works. I am not exactly sure why.

Comment: 1,1,2,0 means: first column ascending, second column descending